# How to inset dash between regex match?

Tags: regex, txt

I need to add - in between of regex match in text file. I tried this but no luck!

```
-L\d{1,2} # this match all I need

Sa-L1
Sa-L23
```

Desire output:

```
Sa-L-1
Sa-L-23
```

There are -L in the lines, but I want to change -L with digits.

Comment: Programming language?

Comment: Just text files

Comment: Use `-L(?=\d{1,2})` instead and replace it with `-L-`. This makes sure the numbers are there but excludes them from the match so they don't get replaced. Also this question is off-topic since it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Super. Thanks. Solved the problem. There are other numbers alone too like -1 so the target is -L[d]. But you solution worked!

Comment: I am sorry, should I delete question then?

Comment: @izoysh, yes, close

Comment: You could replace zero-width matches of `(?<=-L)(?=\d+\b)` with a hyphen. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KkLMqI/1). There's no need to delete your question. Others reading it may find it useful even if there are no answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
(-L)(\d)
```

Replace with `$1-$2` or `\1-\2`.

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/PJo7qU/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -L                       '-L'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
```